# Retrofit and Rxjava "Unable to create converter for java.util.List<Model>"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit2, rx-android

Have been having issue using Rxjava with Retrofit in my android app, everything seems ok and fine in the code implementation but app crashes whenever i navigate to the activity/fragment with the error message below.

```
//Error message
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for java.util.List<com.thebestprice.bestprice.model.SearchRequestModel>
        for method DataEndpointService.getStarredRepositories
```

//Endpoint Declaration

```
@GET("users/{user}/starred")
    Observable<List<SearchRequestModel>> getStarredRepositories(@Path("user") String username);
```

//Client Class

```
public class DataClient {

private static final String PROJECT_BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/";
    private static DataClient instance;
    private DataEndpointService queryResultService;


    private DataClient(){
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES).create();

        final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(PROJECT_BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();

        queryResultService = retrofit.create(DataEndpointService.class);
    }

    public static DataClient getInstance(){
        if (instance == null){
            instance = new DataClient();
        }
        return instance;
    }

public io.reactivex.Observable<List<SearchRequestModel>> queryForUserRepo(@NonNull String searchRequestModel){
        return queryResultService.getStarredRepositories(searchRequestModel);
    }
}
```

//Fragment to display the list

```
private void queryResultForSearchData(String userName){

        disposable = DataClient.getInstance().
                queryForUserRepo(userName).
                subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
                observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
                subscribe(new Consumer<List<SearchRequestModel>>() {
                              @Override
                              public void accept(List<SearchRequestModel> searchRequestModels) throws Exception {
                                  mShimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmerAnimation();
                                  rvAllSearch.setAdapter(new ResultAdapter(getActivity(), searchRequestModels));
                              }
                          },
                        new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                            @Override
                            public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {

                            }`enter code here`
                        });
    }
```

//gradle dependencies for rxjava and retrofit with compileSdk27

```
//For using RxJava
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.12'

    //logging interceptor
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'

    //For Using retrofit to do network request
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'
```

Don't know what i'm doing wrong, have search for similar issues but doesn't seems to help in my own case

Answer (score 0):

Main point of using `RxJava` it's avoid loops and list, to invoke Subscriptions and map functions, cause Observables managed all items. So you don't neet to return `List`.

Just one of example of using  [`Github` API with `Rx`](https://github.com/GensaGames/Sample-Github-RxAndroid-Demo).

```
public interface GithubService {
    String SERVICE_ENDPOINT = "https://api.github.com";

    @GET("/users/{login}")
    Observable<Github> getUserRx(@Path("login") String login);

    @GET("/users/{login}")
    Github getUser(@Path("login") String login);
}
```

.

```
public class ServiceFactory {

    /**
     * Creates a retrofit service from an arbitrary class (clazz)
     * @param clazz Java interface of the retrofit service
     * @param endPoint REST endpoint url
     * @return retrofit service with defined endpoint
     */
    public static <T> T createRetrofitService(final Class<T> tClass, final String endPoint) {
        final RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(endPoint)
                .build();
        T service = restAdapter.create(tClass);

        return service;
    }
}
```

.

```
        // .....
        service = ServiceFactory.createRetrofitService(
                GithubService.class, GithubService.SERVICE_ENDPOINT);

service.getUserRx(login)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .cache()
                    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Github>() {
                        @Override
                        public final void onCompleted() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public final void onError(Throwable e) {
                            Log.e(LOG, " ErrorRx Default Github" + e.getMessage());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public final void onNext(Github response) {
                            mCardAdapter.addData(response);
                        }
                    });

// .....
```

Comment: Can you provide RecyclerAdapter and ViewHolder implemmetation for the above sample ?

Comment: your time is appraciated, when trying to use the above method as you mentioned, i got a comples of error on the RecyclerviewAdapter and the viewholder, kindly shed more light on that

Comment: @sodiqOladeni I attached link to the github with all source. There are very simple example of using Github API and Rx.

Answer (score 0):

As you add GsonConverterFactory.
Check out the Bean you use (SearchRequestModel) the variable or the @SerializedName(alternate) annotation does not have the same variable name.

it work for me